# Why a capacitor improves the power factor and connecting reactor in parallel avoids increase of voltage

Tags: voltage, power, capacitor, inductor

When we read the power transmission or Circuit Theory,the book will teach us two things

> 1.we can  connect the capacitor in parallel to improve the power factor
>
> 2.we can connect the reactor in parallel to avoid the increasing of voltage

1. If we can connect the capacitor in parallel to improve the power factor, can we connect the "inductor" in parallel to improve the power factor? If not, why?
2. Why won't we connect the inductor or capacitor in parallel to avoid the increasing of voltage?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what the book says about (2). I ask because connecting a *reactor in parallel to avoid the increasing voltage* is less clear than the capacitor and power factor thing and I'm thinking that maybe you have not provided enough context.

Comment: but the book is chinese,do you still want it?

Comment: capacitance lower the impedance to fast voltage changes Ic = C dV/dt by shifting the phase of current and drawing more current at higher frequency , Inductance impedes the rise in voltage if current continues after a break or motor stop. V = L dI/dt. this can be expressed in frequency domain as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Power factor comes from the phase shift caused by if a load is "capacitive" or "inductive".

Inductive loads cause the current to lag the voltage, and Capacitive loads cause the voltage to lag the current. Power factor is 1 when these are both in phase.

So with an inductive load such as a motor, the only way to skew the power factor back towards 1 is to use a capacitive load to cancel out the shift.

On the flip side, a capacitive load needs some inductance to shift it back towards 1.

2. When you have a capacitor an inductor in series, depending on the frequency you can reach a "resonance" point, where the voltage across the capacitor will increase to much higher than the mains voltage due to its interaction with the inductor, as the capacitor will fail if the voltage gets too high you want to avoid this. combine this with the fact most AC capacitors will lose capacitance as they age means its not always easy to just calculate the values to avoid that.

Due to this, it is more common to have the loads in parallel, equally it means the load your correcting can run at full line voltage.